# Why do my VSCode compiler and debugger not work unless I am connected to a server?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am a sophomore in college studying computer science. At the beginning of this semester, my professor had me install VSCode and set up SSH. Whenever I am not connected to the server, the debugger doesn't work and the program doesn't run. I suspect it has something to do with how I installed it or the file location. This is (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDYDS.png) the error I am getting.

I tried googling this issue but it doesn't seem to be one mentioned very much.

Comment: what extension and feature are you using the run? what compiler have you installed locally?

Comment: This needs more detail: what extensions do you have? Are compilers, base paths and ENV properly set up? What's in launch.json?